# Public IP not coming in instances from Terraform code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

**Requirement for above code is as below:**
The company wants the Architecture to have the following services:

1. Create a template with a VPC, 2 subnets and 1 instance in each subnet
2. Attach Security groups, internet gateway and network interface to the instance

**Public IP not coming in instances from below Terraform code:
**

```
 # Block Settings
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        aws = {
          source = "hashicorp/aws"
        }
      }
    }

    # Provider
    provider "aws" {
      profile = "default"
      region = "us-east-2"
    }

    # VPC
    resource "aws_vpc" "TF_VPC" {
      cidr_block = "170.31.0.0/16"
    tags = {
    Name = "TF_VPC"
      }
    }

    # Subnets
    resource "aws_subnet" "TF_Subnet1" {
      vpc_id     = aws_vpc.TF_VPC.id
      cidr_block = "170.31.1.0/24"
      availability_zone = "us-east-2a"
    tags = {
    Name = "TF_Subnet1"
      }
    }

    resource "aws_subnet" "TF_Subnet2" {
      vpc_id     = aws_vpc.TF_VPC.id
      cidr_block = "170.31.2.0/24"
      availability_zone = "us-east-2b"
    tags = {
    Name = "TF_Subnet2"
      }
    }

    # Security Group
    resource "aws_security_group" "TF_SG" {
      vpc_id = aws_vpc.TF_VPC.id

      # Allow SSH access from anywhere
      ingress {
        from_port   = 22
        to_port     = 22
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }

      # Allow HTTP access from anywhere
      ingress {
        from_port   = 80
        to_port     = 80
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }

      egress {
        from_port   = 0
        to_port     = 0
        protocol    = "-1"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
     }
    tags = {
    Name = "TF_SG"
      }
    }

    # Internet Gateway
    resource "aws_internet_gateway" "TF_IGW" {
      vpc_id = aws_vpc.TF_VPC.id
    tags = {
    Name = "TF_IGW"
      }
    }

    # Route Table
    resource "aws_route_table" "TF_RT" {
      vpc_id = aws_vpc.TF_VPC.id

        route {
          cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
          gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.TF_IGW.id
    }

    tags = {
    Name = "TF_RT"
      }
    }

    # Route Table Association
    resource "aws_route_table_association" "TF_RTA1" {
      subnet_id      = aws_subnet.TF_Subnet1.id
      route_table_id = aws_route_table.TF_RT.id
} 

    resource "aws_route_table_association" "TF_RTA2" {
      subnet_id      = aws_subnet.TF_Subnet2.id
      route_table_id = aws_route_table.TF_RT.id
}

    # Network Interface
    resource "aws_network_interface" "TF_NI1" {
      subnet_id   = aws_subnet.TF_Subnet1.id
      private_ips = ["170.31.1.5"]
      security_groups = [aws_security_group.TF_SG.id]
    tags = {
    Name = "TF_NI1"
      }
    }

    resource "aws_network_interface" "TF_NI2" {
      subnet_id   = aws_subnet.TF_Subnet2.id
      private_ips = ["170.31.2.5"]
      security_groups = [aws_security_group.TF_SG.id]
    tags = {
    Name = "TF_NI2"
      }
    }

    # EC2 Instances
    resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance1" {
      ami           = "ami-024e6efaf93d85776"
      instance_type = "t2.micro"
      key_name      = "assign.ohio"
        network_interface {
        network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.TF_NI1.id
        device_index         = 0
      }
    tags = {
    Name = "TF_instance1"
      }
    }

    resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance2" {
      ami           = "ami-024e6efaf93d85776"
      instance_type = "t2.micro"
      key_name      = "assign.ohio"
        network_interface {
        network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.TF_NI2.id
        device_index         = 0

      }
    tags = {
    Name = "TF_instance2"
      }
    }
```

All the things are getting created but EC2 instances not getting public IP.
If I use below code under instance:

```
  ami                         = "ami-024e6efaf93d85776"
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  associate_public_ip_address = true ## <-- Add this
  key_name                    = "assign.ohio"
  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.TF_NI1.id
    device_index         = 0

  }
  tags = {
    Name = "TF_instance1"
  }
}
```

Getting error as below:

```
│ 
│   with aws_instance.TF_instance1,
│   on main.tf line 127, in resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance1":
│  127:     resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance1" {
│ 
│ "network_interface": conflicts with associate_public_ip_address
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate public IP on your EC2 instance, example below:

```
resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance2" {
  ami                         = "ami-024e6efaf93d85776"
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  associate_public_ip_address = true ## <-- Add this
  key_name                    = "assign.ohio"
  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.TF_NI2.id
    device_index         = 0

  }
  tags = {
    Name = "TF_instance2"
  }
}
```

Check the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#associate_public_ip_address) for reference.

Comment: if i add this line then there is an error of Network Interface

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you ping the error you are receiving.
Alternatively, you can create Elastic IP and attach to the instance.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eip

Try the below code:

```
resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance2" {
  ami                         = "ami-024e6efaf93d85776"
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  associate_public_ip_address = true ## <-- Add this
  key_name                    = "assign.ohio"
  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.TF_NI2.id
    device_index         = 1

  }
  tags = {
    Name = "TF_instance2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try the code provided and let me know

Comment: Error: Error: Conflicting configuration arguments
│ 
│   with aws_instance.TF_instance1,
│   on main.tf line 127, in resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance1":
│  127:     resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance1" {
│ 
│ "network_interface": conflicts with associate_public_ip_address